# How to put together an HKT30 optical rotary encoder?

Tags: arduino-uno, robotics, rotary-encoder, stepper-motor

I'm working on a project involving stepper motors. It is important for this project to track the position of these motors, so I decided to buy an optical rotary encoder, specifically an HKT30(HKT3005-C03G-1000B-5E) pictured [here](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/image/cache/catalog/encoder/HKT3008-C03G-1000B-5E%201-1000x1000.jpg). I've found it difficult to find resources on how to put this together. I've found datasheets, like [this one](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/download/HKT30-32.pdf), but it does not seem to be made up of the same components I have. I think I've basically gotten the gist of how one puts this together from google images, but I would like to be pointed in the way of an explicit resource in case I damage my parts.

Additionally, I was hoping for an explanation on the 5 wires (red, green, black, white, and gray), their purpose and how to set one up on a board.

If any clarification or images are needed, I would be happy to provide.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard...

- The sensor screws into the screw holes.
- The disc slots into the gap in the sensor
- The case clips on the outside

As to what the wires are, only the datasheet / manual / manufacturer can tell you that. Maybe if you trace them on the sensor board you can work out what is what.

Comment: About that, the disc isn't a tight fit into the sensor. Is that supposed to be the case?

Comment: Of course. It has to be able to spin, doesn't it...